# Check if a condition is respect instantly

Tags: python, events

I have a complex project and I will try to simplify one of the main problem of the project. So there is the simplification:
We can Imagine a while loop like this:

```
while(condition):
     statement1
     statement2
     statement3
     ...
     statementn
```

In this loop there n statements, and each statement can be whatever(function, loop, if statement,...) and there is a condition in the loop, this condition i want to check it BEFORE the while loop do it. Because if the condition is respect since the first statement I have to wait until the end of the while to check if the condition is respect... So there is my question is possible to check the condition BEFORE the loop without have a check-function between EACH statements of the whileloop ?

Because in fact, it's work... BUT the code isn't clear, I really think this way we pollute my code and i want to work more efficiently and with a beautiful code, so how can I solve my problem without this constraint ?

PS: I think about event listener like javascript but i found poor information about them on python, but if there is a tool which act like event listener it would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to clean up all your if-then-break statements into a single function that handles the "checking" of the value of `a`. For that purpose you could use exceptions:

```py
import random

class ItIsFiveException(Exception): pass

def check(a):
  if a == 5:
    raise ItIsFiveException

try:
  a = 0
  while(a != 5):
    a = random.randint(1,5); check(a)
    a = random.randint(1,5); check(a)
    a = random.randint(1,5); check(a)
    a = random.randint(1,5); check(a)
except ItIsFiveException:
  print("I saw a five!")
```

You just have to define your own python Exception as a class, and the raise it in your manually-defined `check(a)` function. Then you can wrap your entire while loop in a try-except block and catch your exception.

Comment: I think you answer to my topic, but i'm not sure i will do some test with the my complex case in project, but this is a really good track !

Comment: It's a really strange way be cause i would never exepect that exception would help me in this case but thanks it works perfectly like i wanted !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you right, but this is what I'd do:

```
flag = False
while not flag:
    for i in range(4):
        a = random.randint(1, 5)
        if a == 4:
            flag = True
            break
```

Comment: Your code is probably good and works in this case, but i think i will bring more precision in my topic

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what it happens with "a" but if if you can chain the conditions and will stop when the first one fails

```
while(checkRandom()):
   ...
def checkRandom(a):
   return random.randint(1,5) == 5 and random.randint(1,5)....
```

If you can loop the generation of random values you can use

```
while(a!=5):
  for item in range(1, 5):
    a=random.randint(1,5)
    if a==5:
       break
```

Comment: Your code is probably good and works in this case, but i think i will bring more precision in my topic

Comment: Maybe try to be more descriptive with the code so we can understand better.